# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null using joomla

Tags: javascript, joomla

this error comes up when using the following :
field **otherinfo** has id=idOtherInfo and is declared in a **.xml** file under Models, Forms in **joomla**.
The field has a default value in the declaration to prevent the null (shows the default value in the browser) and using the 
`onchange="dosomething()"` 
I am running a javascript file, which runs ok as it shows an alert and then it halts on the command 
`var first1 = document.getElementById("idOtherInfo").value;`
The javascript file is loaded by

```
JHtml::script(JURI::root() . 'media/com_hr/js/validateFields.js', true);
```

also can be loaded by

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript(JURI::root().'media/com_hr/js/validateFields.js');
```

Can you please help?
Thanks

Comment: It means that element with ID `idOtherInfo` dosen't exist. Check your source code of web page to be sure that it shows your input correctly.

Comment: I have checked the source code and for reason it changed field id from idOtherInfo to jform_idOtherInfo_lbl. I have no idea why. So i added _lbl on the end of the id. Now it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, Joomla! does it with forms generated from XML. Will add this as answer so others will find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that element with ID `idOtherInfo` dosen't exist. Check your source code of web page to be sure that it shows your input correctly.

**SOLUTION**

If Joomla! generates forms from XML file, it adds `jform_` to start of `input` and `label` ID and `-lbl` to end of `label`.

So for getting input value

```
var first1 = document.getElementById("jform_idOtherInfo").value;
```

and for label

```
var first1 = document.getElementById("jform_idOtherInfo-lbl").innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a long shot but I think you've had a little mix up with the name of the ID. Try changing this:

```
document.getElementById("idOtherInfo").value;
```

to this:

```
document.getElementById("OtherInfo").value;
```

Comment: thanks for help. indeed the problem was with the id. pls see my comments above.thanks